# Construction of morphism in right derived functors in category of abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Consider for the short exact sequence (s.e.s)
\begin{align*}
0 \to \mathbf{Z} \xrightarrow{\cdot 2} \mathbf{Z} \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} \to 0
\end{align*}
the covariant left exact functor $\text{Hom}(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, -): \text{Ab} \to \text{Ab}$. I want to exhibit the long exact sequence associated to this s.e.s. for the right derived functors of $\text{Hom}(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, -)$. We denote the right derived functors of $\text{Hom}(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, -)$ by $\text{Ext}^i(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, - ): \text{Ab} \to \text{Ab}$ for $i \geq 0$. The long exact sequence reduces to
\begin{align*}
0 \to \text{Hom}(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}) \xrightarrow{\delta} \text{Ext}^1(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, \mathbf{Z}) \xrightarrow{\varphi} \text{Ext}^1(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}, \mathbf{Z}) \xrightarrow{\psi} \text{Ext}^1(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} ) \to 0.
\end{align*}
The way I'm trying to understand the three morphisms is by looking at the construction of this long exact sequence. This goes as follows. We first pick two injective resolutions for $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$, with these two we construct an injective resolution for the middle group $\mathbf{Z}$ in the s.e.s.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0\\
@. @VVV  @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> \mathbf{Z} @>\cdot2 >> \mathbf{Z} @>\pi>> \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z} @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @V(\cdot 1/2, \pi)VV @VVV\\
0 @>>> \mathbf{Q} @>>> \mathbf{Q} \oplus \mathbf{Q}/2\mathbf{Z} @>\pi>> \mathbf{Q}/2\mathbf{Z} @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @V\tau VV @VVV\\
0 @>>> \mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z} @>>> \left(\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}\right)^2 @>\pi>> \mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z} @>>> 0\\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0
\end{CD}
The horizontal and vertical arrows that have no annotation are the natural embeddings or projections.

> **Question**: what should the map $\tau$ be? Where $\tau$ should make the vertical sequence exact and it should also make the diagram commutative.

In order to make the vertical sequence exact, I think we have to pick $\tau = (\cdot 2, \iota)$. However, this doesn't make the diagram commutative.

Note that this question is very much related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568698/understanding-the-maps-in-the-long-exact-sequence-of-operatornameext/), however, I am trying to understand the details of this construction. Suggestions for other approaches of understanding the arrows in the long exact sequence are also welcome. But at this moment I don't see how the construction of the long exact sequence can be omitted to understand the arrows.

Note also that if I know what this single arrow $\tau$ is precisely, then we $\text{Hom}$ the diagram and calculate the cohomology groups. The morphisms $\delta,\varphi$ and $\psi$ should then be clear as $\delta$ is given by the snake lemma and the other two are the natural morphisms on cohomology groups.